# why does java use AQS instead of native mutex?

Tags: java, concurrency, mutex

As we know, operating system like linux provides the mutex api to
help synchronizing between multi threads.

However, JAVA also implement its own **AQS** api to achieve the same goal, which in short maintains a blocked queue of waiting thread.

But what's the benefit of **AQS** over direct usage of mutex? Why not just provide a simple api based on mutex?

Comment: Less native code that is different between platforms and a single API?

Comment: Indeed, AQS doesn't have any `native` methods ... or use Unsafe, in Java 11. Other possible reasons: 1) AQS can easily be used from custome Java code (unlike native code implementations).  2) Under the code, AQS could be using a native implementation that is more efficient ... because it is better tuned to Java requirements. 3) AQS has been in Java since Java 1.5, and could (hypothetically) predate advances in the Linux native mutex implementation.

Comment: Java 15 AQS has gone back to using `Unsafe` instead of `VarHandle` for JVM bootstrapping reasons.  It is using this to perform volatile semantic reads and writes and CAS operations.